# How to get Google Apps Script project ID linked/bound to a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have a task to update Apps Scripts linked to some Spreadsheets using Google REST APIs. I know how to update script if I have script Id, but the problem is that I have only spreadsheet Id, and I need to updated linked/bound script.

I didn't find any method in Apps Script REST API that would allow listing scripts linked to a spreadsheet https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/

I also tried Google Drive REST APIs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list and https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to retrieve the bound script id from the parent spreadsheet id. You can star(star on top left) these issues to prioritize these issues:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117105106

Depending on your use case, There's a workaround mentioned by Tanaike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52919838/how-can-i-delete-container-bound-scripts-from-multiple-google-documents-or-sheet#comment92750309_52919838)