# Will a Google App Script carry over to a new Google sheet whilst using [makeCopy] function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way, when using app script to makeCopy of a Google file, to NOT have the app script carry over into the new file? I don't want the user to run the script in the new file, because it will make a copy of a copy and cause problems. And there's gonna be that one person who does it if the app script is there. I don't want the app script copied with the file.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `a Google file` you think?

Comment: I can write a script that will remove data from the file, so it reasons (in my mind) that I can write a script that will remove a script. I can't find the code to do this, and I'm wondering what the correct order would be to make sure the script is only removed from the new file, not the original file. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I asked about the mimeType of `a Google file`. Because from your question, I cannot understand about the kind of the file of `a Google file`.

Comment: He is talking about spreadsheets, docs, etc where the script can be written as bounded to the file. When you make a copy of the sheet, then the script will also get copied. Michael doesn't want the script to be copied when creating a new file.

Comment: It is a Google Sheets file. I apologize in advance if I still misunderstand the question and this does not help. Thank you

Comment: @Anees Hameed Thank you for your support.

Comment: @Michael Honeycutt Thank you for replying. In the case of Spreadsheet, I think that this is the direct answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51790433