# GScript- Optimise time of script to fetch data from one G ss to another

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope you are doing well, I have tried all related topic to find an answer to the following question but I could not find a good answer to my problem.

Here is my problem: I wrote a very simple script to fetch data from several spreadsheet into 1 but my script usually fails since it is taking too much computation" 
I can understand my script is not optimised but I am not sure how to proceed to avoid so much calculation {apprently the solution would be storing in an array but I do not know the best way to do that}

I would appreciate your help on that! 
Thanks :)

```
function fetchCluster14ApplicantTrackers() {



  var masterSheet1 = 'link1';
  var masterSheet2 = 'link2';
  var masterSheet3 = 'link3';
  var masterSheet4 = 'link4';

  var tagetedSheet = 'Applicant_Tracker';

  var cluster1Pipeline1 = SpreadsheetApp
  .openByUrl(masterSheet1)
  .getSheetByName(tagetedSheet);

  var cluster1Pipeline2 = SpreadsheetApp
 .openByUrl(masterSheet2)
 .getSheetByName(tagetedSheet);

  var cluster1Pipeline3 = SpreadsheetApp
  .openByUrl(masterSheet3)
  .getSheetByName(tagetedSheet);

   var cluster1Pipeline4 = SpreadsheetApp
  .openByUrl(masterSheet4)
  .getSheetByName(tagetedSheet);


  var getcluster1DataPipeline1 = 
  cluster1Pipeline1.getRange(1,3,11000,33).getValues();
  var getcluster1DataPipeline2 = 
  cluster1Pipeline2.getRange(1,3,5000,33).getValues();
  var getcluster1DataPipeline3 = 
  cluster1Pipeline3.getRange(1,3,5000,33).getValues();
  var getcluster1DataPipeline4 = 
  cluster1Pipeline4.getRange(1,3,5000,33).getValues();


  var fetchPipeline1 = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pipeline1');
  var fetchPipeline2 = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pipeline2');
  var fetchPipeline3 = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pipeline3');
  var fetchPipeline4 = 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('pipeline4');




    fetchPipeline1.getRange(1,10,11000,33)
    .setValues(getcluster1DataPipeline1);  

    fetchPipeline2.getRange(1,10,5000,33)
    .setValues(getcluster1DataPipeline2);  

    fetchPipeline3.getRange(1,10,5000,33)
    .setValues(getcluster1DataPipeline3);  

    fetchPipeline4.getRange(1,10,5000,33)
    .setValues(getcluster1DataPipeline4);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, each value is retrieved from 4 Spreadsheets, then they are put to 4 sheets in a Spreadsheet. I think that each function can be worked individually. So how about this workaround? In this workaround, Sheets API is used. The flow is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from 4 Spreadsheets.
2. Put the values to 4 sheets.

I would like to propose to run above flow with the asynchronous processing using the fetchAll method. This fetchAll method was added at January 19, 2018. And it has already been known that this method works by the asynchronous processing.

When you use this modified script, please enable Sheets API at API console. You can see about how to enable Sheets API at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754286/retrieving-google-sheets-cell-border-style-programmatically/48756509#48756509).

#### Modified script:

```
function fetchCluster14ApplicantTrackers() {
  // Please set SpreadsheetId of source Spreadsheet.
  var sourceSpreadsheets = [
    {id: "### SpreadsheetId of masterSheet1 ###", range: "link1!C1:AI11000"},
    {id: "### SpreadsheetId of masterSheet2 ###", range: "link2!C1:AI5000"},
    {id: "### SpreadsheetId of masterSheet3 ###", range: "link3!C1:AI5000"},
    {id: "### SpreadsheetId of masterSheet4 ###", range: "link4!C1:AI5000"},
  ];

  var destinationSpreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var destinationSheets = [
    {range: "pipeline1!J1:AP11000"},
    {range: "pipeline2!J1:AP5000"},
    {range: "pipeline3!J1:AP5000"},
    {range: "pipeline4!J1:AP5000"},
  ];
  var accessToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // Get values.
  var requests1 = sourceSpreadsheets.map(function(e) {
    return {
      url: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + e.id + "/values/" + encodeURIComponent(e.range) + "?fields=values",
      method: "get",
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken},
    };
  });
  var values = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests1);

  // Put values.
  var requests2 = destinationSheets.map(function(e, i) {
    return {
      url: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + destinationSpreadsheetId + "/values/" + encodeURIComponent(e.range) + "?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED",
      method: "put",
      payload: values[i],
      contentType: "application/json",
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken},
    }
  });
  UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests2);
}
```

#### Note:

- Before you run the script, please set the variables.

  - `id` is the [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id).
- If The process was not improved using this workaround, please check [this GAS library](https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll). By using this GAS library, both retrieving and putting values can be run by the asynchronous processing.

#### References:

- [fetchAll method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))
- [fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)
- [Spreadsheet ID](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id)

If this workaround was not the result you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Tanaike,Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, let me try that and revert back to you. Best regards,Avi

Comment: @AYCO Thank you for replying. If this workaround was not the result you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: I followed your method and enable Sheet API from API console - I am using a simple key and here is the message I have Request failed for /https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1bn3bnw8fi9ALUT6sGbxb2y61rq17KlgJZRQZKR29Vp8/values/link1!C1%3AAI11000?fields=values returned code 401. Truncated server response: { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or othe... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 27, file "test") / I might have miss something ^^, right ?

Comment: @AYCO I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. In order to understand correctly about your current situation, can you provide your latest script, and also, can you show me the flow you did? If you can do, please add it to your question. Because in my environment, my script works fine.

Comment: @AYCO Although I tried my script again, I could confirm that the script worked. If Sheets API is not enabled, other error occurs. In the case of your error message, when the access token cannot be used, the error occurs. So I would like to know about your current situation.