# Practical use case of DeveloperMetadata in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I recently found published new Classes and methods of Spreadsheet related to [DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata), and I am seeking code examples showing practical use of such data structures.

I have tried to grasp the idea of metadata, but so far it is too confusing for me.

Let's suppose this scenario - I'm developing some automation for spreadsheets. There is table with orders (date, customer name, sold item name, price, etc). In bounded script I address price column like this `sheet.getRange("H:H")` (hardcoded). But when an user of the sheet change position of a column "H" somewhere else the script will stop working properly - unless I change in code "H" to new column letter.

I am seeking some real GAS code (not Advanced Sheet services) which will show how easily handle this situation.

I'm imagining something like this (pseudo-code):

```
sheet.getRange("H:H").setMatadata("columnName","price"); //First set column identification

var priceColumnRange = sheet.getMetadaDataByKey("price").getRange(); //Then retrieve column range by its identification
```

I found a way how to set metadata to a range, but I didn't find a way how to easily retrieve (search/find) this data. It looks really difficult from documentation, and I still don't know how to use metadata for such an easy task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+developerMetadata https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+developer%20Metadata

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/metadata

Comment: Thx for links, I studied them, but none of them presents real GAS code representing real use case for developerMetadata :-(

Comment: I have some rudimentary scripts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553028/7215091).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to search and retrieve DeveloperMetadata from rows and columns using Class DeveloperMetadata.

  - You want the sample scripts for above situation.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? I tried to think of about this situation because this is also useful for my situation. I think that there are several sample scripts for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, all DeveloperMetadata is retrieved from the sheet which has the sheet name of "Sheet1".

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var v = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getMaxRows(), s.getMaxColumns()).createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().find();
var res = v.map(function(e) {
  var loc = e.getLocation();
  var obj = loc.getLocationType() === SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.COLUMN ? {range: loc.getColumn().getA1Notation()} :
    loc.getLocationType() === SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataLocationType.ROW ? {range: loc.getRow().getA1Notation()} : {};
  obj[e.getKey()] = e.getValue();
  return obj;
});
Logger.log(res)
```

- As a sample situation, after DeveloperMetadata is set to the column "A", when it is moved to the column "B", this script retrieves the key and values of column "B".
- For example, if you want to search using key and value, you can also use the following scripts.

  - `var v = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getMaxRows(), s.getMaxColumns()).createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withKey("key1").find();`
  - `var v = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getMaxRows(), s.getMaxColumns()).createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withValue("value").find();`
  - `var v = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getMaxRows(), s.getMaxColumns()).createDeveloperMetadataFinder().onIntersectingLocations().withKey("key1").withValue("value1").find();`
- This is a sample script. So please modify this for your situation.

#### Result:

When 2 DeveloperMetadata of `{key1: "value1"}` and `{key2: "value2"}` are set to row 1 and column A, the following result is obtained.

```
[
  {
    "range": "1:1",
    "type": "ROW",
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  {
    "range": "A:A",
    "type": "COLUMN",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
]
```

### Sample script 2:

As another way, you can also search DeveloperMetadata using Sheets API as follows. When you use Sheets API, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about how to enable Sheets API at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756509).

```
var resource = {"dataFilters": [{"developerMetadataLookup": {"metadataKey": "key1"}}]}; // Search by key
// var resource = {"dataFilters": [{"developerMetadataLookup": {"metadataValue": "value1"}}]}; // Search by value
// var resource = {"dataFilters": [{"developerMetadataLookup": {"metadataKey": "key1", "metadataValue": "value1"}}]}; // Search by key and value
var res = Sheets.Spreadsheets.DeveloperMetadata.search(resource, spreadsheetId);
```

### References:

- [Class DeveloperMetadata](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata)
- [spreadsheets.developerMetadata.search](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

### Edit:

For your 2nd question.

1. Add a metadata to "H:H" as the key of "columnName" and the value of "price".
2. Envn if the column "H" was moved, you want to retrieve the new range using the value of metadata.

If my understanding is correct, how about this?

#### Add metadata

In order to add a metadata to the column "H", you can use the following script. Because there is no method of `setMatadata()`, please use `addDeveloperMetadata()`.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("H:H").addDeveloperMetadata("columnName", "price");
```

#### Retrieve ranges using value

This sample script retrieves ranges using a value of metadata. In this script, envn if the column "H" was moved, the new range using the value of metadata can be retrieved.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var value = "price";
var v = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns())
  .createDeveloperMetadataFinder()
  .onIntersectingLocations()
  .withValue(value)
  .find();
var ranges = v.map(function(e) {return e.getLocation().getColumn()}); // "ranges" is one dimensional array.
```

Comment: Thx for your script mate.. It gave me new energy to dig deeper in MD (study documentation, make some test with it).. But I didn't the idea how to really use MD yet.. I edited my question based on my digging after you answer so its more practical. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Jindřich Širůček I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. I added an answer for your next question. Could you please confirm it? If that is not what you want, I have to apologize.

Comment: @Jindřich Širůček Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Its quite complicated to use MD for such an easy task. But i can see how it works now, so I can use it when needed for some more complicated situations - thank you.
(I had to test the script before marking answer as answered, it needed some time)

Comment: @Jindřich Širůček Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that the metadata will be useful for creating applications. I would like to take advantage of it.

Comment: I find that the searches seem to take a long time.  Is that consistent with your experience?

Comment: @MetaMan I think that the process cost for retrieving the DeveloperMetadata is high. Especially, when the Spreadsheet service of `SpreadsheetApp` is used, I felt that the cost is very high. So, in this case, I used Sheets API. I felt that when Sheets API is used, the cost of this is lower than that of Spreadsheet service.

Comment: @MetaMan But, above situation is before V8 runtime is released. So, if you need the quantitative information, I think that it is required to measure the process cost under the current situation with V8 runtime.

Comment: Yeah I'm not talk about the above code.  I was learning about it today a little and I came up with some example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553028/7215091) which is running under V8 for a range of 21 rows and 10 columns

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super simplified example:

```
const initialize = () => {
  spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadSheet.addDeveloperMetadata("initializeDone", "true", SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT)
  
  const metaData = spreadSheet.getDeveloperMetadata();
  Logger.log('Metadata key: ' + metaData[0].getKey()); // "initializedDone"
  Logger.log('Metadata value: ' + metaData[0].getValue()); // "true"
}
```

Notice the `[0]` reference: the metaData object is kind of like an array containing many elements. But you still need to use the DeveloperMetadataFinder to search based on key or value:

```
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const finder = spreadSheet.createDeveloperMetadataFinder();
  metaData = finder.withKey('initializeDone').find();
  Logger.log(metaData[0].getValue()); // "true"
```