# Google apps script: autoResizeColumn works incorrectly not works as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am trying to resize the column1 to column 10 through google app scripts using the below code.

```
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 10);
```

The columns are resized but not as expected.

I expected like this
[image]
but actually I got this
[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78661919

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the method of "autoResizeColumns" in Class Sheet has the issue yet. So how about this workaround? When I had tried the auto resize using Sheets API, I noticed that the results are different between Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) and Sheets API. By using this, I use the method of "AutoResizeDimensionsRequest" in Sheets API as a current workaround.

**When you use Sheets API, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about how to enable Sheets API at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756509).**

#### Sample script:

When `sheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 10)` in your script is converted to the script using Sheets API, it becomes as follows.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var resource = {"requests": [{"autoResizeDimensions": {"dimensions": {
  "dimension": "COLUMNS",
  "sheetId": ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getSheetId(),
  "startIndex": 0,
  "endIndex": 10,
}}}]};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, it seems that this workaround can avoid the issue of Spreadsheet service. But if this was not the result you want, I apologize.

#### Reference:

- [AutoResizeDimensionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#autoresizedimensionsrequest)

Comment: I used your code for testing but I got an error ie.,
TypeError: Cannot call method "batchUpdate" of undefined. (line 81, file "functiontest")

Comment: Working fine after I enable API services

Comment: @StackUser Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I expect that the issue of SpreadsheetApp will resolve in the future.

Answer (score -1):

By now it's only possible to use [`autoResizeColumn`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=pt-br#autoresizecolumncolumnposition). So an alternative code could be:

```js
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
for(let i=1; i <= 10; i++){
sheet.autoResizeColumn(i);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The problem is not solved using this code, the result is exactly the same as using `sheet.autoResizeColumns(i, numberOfColumns)`