# Autoresizecolumns is too short on Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a very simple sheet with very simple lines of code. When I try to autoresize, it resize almost correctly, but is too short and some cell values are cut.
I use this line for resizing.

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().autoResizeColumns(3,13);

Thanks

I tried resizing the first row, cause it seemed like the most affected at first.
I tried changing the data validation appearance to "chip" and "plain text".

I'm expecting to have all values completely showing on cells.

Here's the link to a "dummy" sheet since I didn't want to share financial informations.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16kFQr5lUbRdI4LquueqUHYizaoweI7ef6zMhdndW1r0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Autoresizing works properly for me. It will be helpful if you can share the sheet/ screenshot for us to clearly understand what the issue is.

Comment: @VeganGeek check `wrapStrategy` in your spreadsheet

Comment: @ab.it.gcp I shared a dummy sheet that acts the same. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonio I tried changing the wrapping on the columns nothing seems to work properly even if they all give a different result.

Comment: add the ability to edit

Comment: With your data, autoResizeColumns does not seem to work as expected. I'd suggest creating an issue with Google on this and share complete details including the sheet. Also, if this task is urgent, then meanwhile to unblock yourself, please try autoresizing using Sheets API to see if that works. Refer the accepted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516371/google-apps-script-autoresizecolumn-works-incorrectly-not-works-as-expected for more details.

Comment: @Antonio Sorry, I don't do this often. I changed it.