# Google script to select rows in Google sheets and clear contents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to try and clear rows ready to delete that contain a specific word within google sheets, the problem i have is the script i have gone with delete lines 1 by 1 which can take a long time if you have a lot of row to search through, where if i could just highlight all those rows and clear the data if the row cantains the specific word then that would be a lot quicker as i could sort the data afterwards

```
function deleteRows() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of TBC Sort');
 var r = s.getRange('C3:C400');
var v = r.getValues();
for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 if(v[0,i]=='Delete Row')
  s.deleteRow(i+1);
 };
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your problem is. Please try to structure your question and, please, use dots in your text.

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54643065/7108653

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearContent()` instead. For more details check the Apps Script website [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).

The example shown is

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D10");
range.clearContent();
```

Comment: OK but how would i select all rows that contain the specfic text so i can clear them?

Answer (score 2):

#### Goal:

Delete rows if data contains "Delete Row".

---

#### Script:

```
function findAndDeleteRow() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of TBC Sort');
  var r = s.getRange('C3:C400');
  var find = r.createTextFinder('Delete Row').findAll().reverse();
  if (find.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
      s.deleteRow(find[i].getRow());
    }
  }
}
```

I've used `createTextFinder()` to find every row that contains your string "Delete Row" (this is faster than looping through an array of values to compare each and every one). This pushes all of the ranges to an array in `var find`. Then we use `reverse()` to reverse the array so we're deleting rows from the bottom up. I've included an `if` statement just to check that there are items in the array to process, then we have a `for` loop to loop through each of the items in the array, passing the row to `deleteRow()` as we go.

**Note: make sure your** `var r` **is a valid range in the spreadsheet or the** `createTextFinder` **will hang.**

---

#### References:

- [`createTextFinder()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [`array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [`deleteRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

Answer (score 1):

Building on what mario said, the fastest thing is to copy the data, clear the range, and paste back the data you want

```
function deleteRows() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of TBC Sort');
var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
var results = [];
for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 if(data[0,i]=='Delete Row') continue;//skips these rows
 result.push(data[i]);
 };
s.getDataRange().clear();
s.getRange(1, 1,results.length, results[0].length).setValues(results);
}
```

Delete row just takes too long