# google apps script how to copy conditional formating in antoher sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google spreadsheet with dozens of identical sheets regarding the format. I have to apply the same conditional formating to all the sheets, so I would like to make it manually on the first sheet, then use Google Apps Script to apply the conditional formating to all the other sheets. I have done the coding below but I get an error that says, translated from french, "The conditional formating rule can't refer to antoher sheet".

```
function myFunction() {
  var my_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet(); 

  var all_sheets = my_spreadsheet.getAllSheets();  
  var source_sheet = all_sheets[0];  
  var source_rules = source_sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();

  var destination_sheet;

  for (var i=1; i<=all_sheets.length-1; i++){
    destination_sheet = all_sheets[i];
    destination_sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(source_rules); 
  }    
}
```

Do you know how can I copy conditional formating from one sheet to another using Google Apps Script or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

- You want to copy the conditional formats in a source sheet to all other sheets.

If my understanding is correct, how about using Sheets API? I thought the the reason that such error occurs might be the information of the source sheet is included in the conditional formats. By this consideration, I modified the sheet information using Sheets API for copying the conditional formats. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

**When you use Sheets API, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services and API console. You can see about how to enable Sheets API at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48756509).**

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var my_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = my_spreadsheet.getId();
  var all_sheets = my_spreadsheet.getSheets();
  var source_sheet = all_sheets[0].getSheetName();

  var srcConditionalFormats = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {ranges: source_sheet, fields: "sheets/conditionalFormats"});
  all_sheets.shift();
  var cf = srcConditionalFormats.sheets[0].conditionalFormats;
  var reqs = all_sheets.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    return ar.concat(cf.map(function(f, j) {
      var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(f));
      temp.ranges = temp.ranges.map(function(g, k) {
        g.sheetId = e.getSheetId();
        return g;
      });
      return {addConditionalFormatRule: {rule: temp}};
    }));
  }, []);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: reqs}, spreadsheetId);
}
```

In this script, the following flow is run.

1. Retrieve the conditional format object from the source sheet using `Spreadsheets.get()`.

   - From your script, it supposes that the source sheet is the 1st index of the sheets.
2. Create the request body for `Spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`.

   - At this time, the sheet information (sheetId) is modified.
3. Request the created request body using `Spreadsheets.batchUpdate()`.

#### Note:

- In your script, there is a spelling miss at `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet()` and no method is used at `my_spreadsheet.getAllSheets()`. But in your question, it is written that the error of `The conditional formating rule can't refer to antoher sheet` occurs. From this situation, I thought this might be due to miswriting of when you posted the question.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Ok thanks for this detailed answer, I'll have a look in Sheets API. The two spelling miss is just a copy error when I posted this question, in my original code I have well getActiveSpreadSheet and my_spreadsheet.getSheets().

Comment: @Thomas Perrin Thank you for replying. In my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. But if this didn't work at your environment, I apologize.

Comment: @Thomas Perrin Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: I am not at work this week, I planned to do this next week!

Comment: @Thomas Perrin Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for the result.